# Using different drawable resources for different screen sizes,does it increase the size of the app?

Tags: android

I know in android studio,I can use drawables for different screen sizes by storing them in `drawable-hdpi` or `drawable-xhdpi` etc.

*My question is will it increase the size of the app?*

Let's say I have 50 images in my app.Then for coping up with different screen sizes I will at least need 50 x 5 =250 images(Same images with different sizes).

Won't it greatly affect the size of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using drawable for each resolution then app size will increase.

If you are using the [Android app Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/) then it reduces the APK size by split the APK based on resolution.

But you can use [Vector drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) to reduce the APK size. Vector drawable is an XML file. This XML file used in across all resolution. It can be scaled without loss of display quality, which means the same file is resized for different screen densities without loss of image quality.